# Does the miner program used affect the hashrate?

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining, hashrate, hashrate-comparison

While mining Monero I have noticed the the hashrate is different depending on the miner used:

When I use the xmr-stack miner I get 100H/s approximately between the CPU and GPU.

When I use Minergate I get 45 H/s on the CPU and 110 H/s on the GPU, that totals 155 H/s.

Why is there such a difference?

Comment: This is likely a configuration issue, xmr-stak is usually faster than Minergate. Add your configuration and hardware details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different programs do things differently, some faster, some slower, so yes, which miner you use has an impact on your hash rate on the same hardware. The differences are usually minimal for the main contenders though. AFAIK the Minergate miner is javascript, which is going to be slower than something like Wolf's minerd (at least for the CPU miner, since the GPU one is probably a precompiled kernel).