# What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mining

I've just started mining on my laptop, I know it isn't much but I wanted to give it a try. I started with Minergate and was getting almost 25 H/s, then I read that this site is a scam because it shows fake H/s numbers so I decided to mine with xmrig, which is recommended in Monero's subreddit.

The problem is that I'm only getting 11.3 H/s max. Am I doing something wrong?

This is hwo I run xmrig:

```
xmrig.exe -o pool.supportxmr.com:3333 -u <my_address> -p x --donate-level=1 --max-cpu-usage=95 -k
```

Comment: Be careful when giving out that address, people can just Google it and will find this thread.

Comment: Same question was asked yesterday: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7284/does-the-miner-program-used-affect-the-hashrate

Comment: What does H/s stand for?

Comment: Hashes per second

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specs of your laptop, but that sounds like a plausible hashrate if your laptop is older or running other applications.

I have a desktop that using the xmr-stak miner can just squeeze 86H/s out of an overclocked i7 2600k. Given the restrictions placed on processors in laptops, I would imagine that they can be far lower than that.

Try using different miners if you haven't already, but be aware that CPU mining is not profitable compared to the enegry input. GPUs, particularity AMD GPUs, are much more efficient per watt when mining on Cryptonight (Monero's algorithm) and tend to effect the overall usability of your machine less.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is old but using Minergate I got more H/s than when using xmrig, if it were the laptop, in both miners I should've gotten about the same amount of H/s, right?

Energy cost is not a problem, tho.

Comment: You said it yourself though, Minergate can display fake hashrates. Try xmr-stak, and compare your results.

Answer (score 0):

I mean you won't be able to withdraw any until you reach a high enough threshold which you probably won't with 25H/S but if you are going to mine any I'd recommend xmrig for cpu and set the number of threads to the number of cores you have. If you're really looking to squeeze the last penny out of your rig recompile xmrig to remove the dev-fee, however bare in mind that your not supporting them for their hard work.